# CSS : Div placement in column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem to place some div.I have the following structure :

```
<div class='box'>
  <div class='boxTitle'><span class='name_field'>my_first_field</span></div>
  <div class= 'boxContent'><div class='JSDIV'>my_first_content</div></div> 
  <div class='boxBottom'></div>
</div>

<div class='box'>
  <div class='boxTitle'><span class='name_field'>my_second_field</span></div>
  <div class= 'boxContent'>
    <div class='JSDIV'>
      <span id='id_field_toJS'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='boxBottom'>  .</div>
</div>
```

The JSDIV class allow me to execute some javascript on this field. boxTitle, box Content and boxBottom allow me to, using a framework, set somme beautiful css on those ones and obtain from "box" div class something really good.
But the problems are :
-The div class "boxBottom" must have a character to be displayed, if i let a space it disappear. It is sad beacause it is diplaying the bottom of the box and without it, the box seem to be cut.
-I don't know the way to make two, or three colums with each "box".
When I try ".box{ display :inline}" each div is  set awfully.
Some pictures would help to understand.

This is a normal box, and following the same bow when the div "boxBottom" is empty (presently I add a point "." to fill it with one character" : !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtbYV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtbYV.png

Now, the disposition I would expect : 
i.stack.imgur.com/szWfT.png

And what I obtain when I set .box{display :inline;} (only on one box, all the others do the same problem)
i.stack.imgur.com/B3nRX.png

I recognize that my question is not really simple owing to the use of a framework but here it might only be fitted div which have to be placed in two, or three columns. I hope jQuery would do that but I didn't found any function that treats all the divs.

Thank you for reading me !! ( sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images correctly, so I used another way to do it. Just add "https://" before links to see please.

Hugo.

Comment: or better yet, make a jsfiddle

Comment: when you say 'if i let a space it disappear' you mean you used &nbsp; and it disappears? if not try using the non breaking space

Comment: I will make a jsFiddle it will be better, and open a new subject. Moreover, problem about bottom of the box solved. This will be more clear. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have an height in the `contentBottom` div put a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) or specify a minimum height using the css property `min-height`

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be:

```
<div class='boxBottom'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```